# Terraform aws_lb_target_group dynamic ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to build AWS Target Groups based on an existing variable which is used to build Security Groups.  I understand I cannot nest `for_each` statements and the `aws_lb_target_group:port` attribute doesn't support a dynamic block.  How can I loop over the facility ports to create the 7 target groups from this example?  How could I refactor the variable to support this?

```
facility-sg-port-map = {
  Facility1 = {
    ports       = [20000, 20001]
    cidr_blocks = ["192.168.0.0/24"]
  }
  Facility2 = {
    ports       = [20010]
    cidr_blocks = ["192.168.1.0/24"]
  }
  FacilityN = {
    ports       = [20020, 20021, 20022, 20023]
    cidr_blocks = ["192.168.2.0/24"]
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "facility-sg" {
  name        = "facility-sg-${var.accountName}"
  description = "Security Group for Facilities"
  vpc_id      = module.vpc.id
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    to_port     = 0
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  dynamic "ingress" {
    iterator = facility
    for_each = var.facility-sg-port-map
    content {
      description = facility.key
      from_port   = element(facility.value.ports, 0)
      protocol    = "tcp"
      to_port     = element(facility.value.ports, length(facility.value.ports) - 1)
      cidr_blocks = facility.value.cidr_blocks
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "facility_target_groups" {
  for_each = var.facility-sg-port-map

  name                 = substr(each.key, 0, 32)
  vpc_id               = module.vpc.id
  protocol             = "TCP"
  port                 = element(each.value.ports, 0)
  target_type          = "instance"
  deregistration_delay = 10
  preserve_client_ip   = true
  health_check {
    protocol            = "TCP"
    enabled             = true
    interval            = 30
    port                = "traffic-port"
    healthy_threshold   = 3
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
    timeout             = 10
  }
  tags = {
    Facility = each.key
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by flattening the variable into a local variable using nested `for` loops:

```
locals {
  facility_tgs = flatten([
    for facility_key, facility in var.facility-sg-port-map: [
      for ports in facility.ports : { 
        facility_key = facility_key
        port = ports
      }
    ]
  ])
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "facility_target_groups" {
  for_each = tomap({
    for tg in local.facility_tgs : "${tg.facility_key}.${tg.port}" => tg
  })

  name                 = "${substr(each.value.facility_key, 0, 25)}-${each.value.port}"
  vpc_id               = module.vpc.id
  protocol             = "TCP"
  port                 = each.value.port
  target_type          = "instance"
  deregistration_delay = 10
  preserve_client_ip   = true
  health_check {
    protocol            = "TCP"
    enabled             = true
    interval            = 30
    port                = "traffic-port"
    healthy_threshold   = 3
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
    timeout             = 10
  }
  tags = {
    Facility = each.value.facility_key
  }
}
```

Comment: with the `substr(each.value.facility_key, 0, 32)` you run into the possibility of duplicate names ... what will happen in that case?

Comment: Yes, it certainly did result in duplicates.  I updated the answer above.

Comment: While this is working, is there a more efficient method?

Comment: this is good enough